# Automatically fill to today's date

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm making a simple web app to help me track how much weights I lift in the gym. I'm trying to add a field that will automatically pick the date of my workouts without me entering in anything.

For example if yesterday I worked on my shoulders I want it to be shown as:

Date: 03 December 2017

I tried adding DateTime.Now.ToLongDateString() in my view however this constantly updates the date to the current day, therefore tomorrow it would show yesterday's shoulder's workout as having been on the 05 December 2017.

Here is my Model:

```
public class Shoulders
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Display(Name ="Military Press")]
    public double MilitaryPress { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Sides Launch")]
    public double SidesLaunch { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Front Launch")]
    public double FrontLaunch { get; set; }
}
```

And here is my View:

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-hover">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Date</th>
        <th>Military Press</th>
        <th>Sides Launch</th>
        <th>Front Launch</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    @foreach (var workout in Model)
        {
        <tr>
            <td>@DateTime.Now.ToLongDateString()</td>
            <td>@workout.MilitaryPress</td>
            <td>@workout.SidesLaunch</td>
            <td>@workout.FrontLaunch</td>
        </tr>
    }
</tbody>
```

Comment: Your model doesn't contain a date.

Comment: You need to clarify what you really want. Because what you have, does what your title suggests, it adds today’s date. If you want the date you created the entry in the dB (assuming it’s the day you did the workout) you need a DateTime property in the class to store it.

Comment: You need to save your date as well or it will keep taking the current day's date because you are using `DateTime.Now`

Comment: After I add a Datetime to my model, how do I make it set automatically?

Comment: You set it based on the Date field in your database - just as you did for the other properties in your model

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your class

```
public class Shoulders
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Display(Name ="Military Press")]
    public double MilitaryPress { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Sides Launch")]
    public double SidesLaunch { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Front Launch")]
    public double FrontLaunch { get; set; }       
}
```

Should be changed to

```
public class Shoulders
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    // you can change set; to private set; if you add the constructor
    public DateTime WorkoutDate { get; set; }

    [Display(Name ="Military Press")]
    public double MilitaryPress { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Sides Launch")]
    public double SidesLaunch { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Front Launch")]
     public double FrontLaunch { get; set; }

     // if you want it set automatically add this constructor
    public Shoulders()
    {
        WorkoutDate = DateTime.Now();
    }
}
```

Then you can set the date when you insert your entry to the database

```
var shoulders = new Shoulders
{
    WorkoutDate = DateTime.Now();
    //other properties set here and if you added the constructor in the 
    // class you don't need to set the date here
};
```

and insert it into the db.

```
context.Shoulders.Add(shoulder);
```

and in your view use

```
@model.WorkoutDate.ToShortDateString();
```

Comment: Sorry forgot to do so. Rectified that now :)